# how do I create a dump file from my subversion hosting account?

Tags: svn

I have my SVN repository hosted somewhere.  I want to move to somebody else.  How can I create a dump of my repository so I can import it into my new host?  This is all I keep seeing:  svnadmin dump /path/to/repos > repos.dump

My repository is hosted, so it's not local.

Comment: Use `svnrdump`. It appeared in svn 1.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

svnadmin dump is the recommended way to [migrating your repositories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.5), but you'll need shell access to do it, otherwise you will have to contact your hosting provider and ask them to do the full repository dump for you.

Comment: Since Subversion 1.7 there is a tool called `svnrdump` which you can use to create a dump file from a remote repository.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.c.help.html) to create a copy of your repository.

This requires adding a pre-revprop-change hook on the destination repository (and requires a Subversion 1.4 or newer repository at your hosting provider).

After you svnsync'ed your repository to a system you manage, you can use svnadmin to dump the local copy if you need a dumpfile (or just use the synced to repository).

[Update in 2011:]
Since Subversion 1.7 there is a tool called `svnrdump` which you can use to create a dump file from a remote repository in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a [remote SVN dump command](http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/).  I haven't used it but it claims to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Some hosted repositories provide means to order an SVN dump file, either included in the price or for an additional monthly fee.  If they don't, you can always do an svnsync without having to involve the hosting company.

Take a look at your destination provider's import capabilities as well.  At [ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com), we support import of a remote repository that is visible over the Internet if you provide the URL to the source repository and your credentials.  I don't believe we are the only host to do this.  That capability saves you the trouble of learning svnsync, and you can focus on moving your code and getting back to writing software.