# Svn full dump (moving servers)

Tags: svn, svn-export

How would I get a full copy of an SVN repository and import it on another server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to perform an `svnadmin dump`.  You can get help on this command via `svnadmin help dump` or [reading the docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html).  You can then load the dump file into your new server using `svnadmin load`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the physical server (and the server runs Subversion 1.4 or later) you could use svnsync to create a local copy of the complete repository.

After that you can use svnadmin to create a dumpfile from your local copy.

See also [How do I create a dump file from my subversion hosting account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354994/how-do-i-create-a-dump-file-from-my-subversion-hosting-account/356353#356353)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the repository type. If you're using fsfs, you can just copy the directory after stopping the server (to make sure you don't copy a transaction which is half completed). I've done that before and it worked flawlessly.

If you're using `bdb` you should do an `svnadmin dump` instead. (If the old and new computers are similar in terms of architecture and OS you may well just get away with a directory copy, but dumping the repository would be safer.)

Comment: if you just copy the directory using the OS file copy command, you run the risk of corruption.  You can use "svnadmin hotcopy" to perform a copy as you describe without the risk of corruption.  The dump/load cycle is usually preferred however, as it allows for loading into a different version of SVN

Comment: Would probably work, though I would probably be worried about it for days. svnadmin dump seems like a more reliable solution.

Comment: @rmeador: Assuming you stop the server first (which I'll edit my answer to mention) why do you risk corruption? What could go wrong?

Comment: If the repo isn't in use, I think you're safe.  Using "svnadmin hotcopy" is just The Right Way according to the SVN developers, especially if the repo is in use.