# Create SVN dump without svnadmin

Tags: svn

I have my SVN hosted with a private provider who does not offer svnadmin dump to create my own backups. All I can do is use an SVN client.

I want to be able to use normal svn command lines and create a dump file so I can either back it up or move my SVN repo somewhere else whilst maintaining the history.

Is there any way I can do this? Or will I have to just have to lose the history and relocate.

Comment: This link might be resourceful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354994/how-do-i-create-a-dump-file-from-my-subversion-hosting-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication).

Here are detailed instructions:

- create a fresh local repo on your local machine
- use **svnsync init** to connect your local repository to your provider's
- use **svnsync sync** to replicate the repository to your machine

By this you maintain a local copy on your machine

Keep in mind that your local repository should not get changes from other places than via **svnsync sync**. But it is the easiest and most convenient way to keep a local backup.

Comment: Does this mean I have to install an SVN server locally? Is there any way to point it at another existing remote server?

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I was able to do this with remote destination and a remote source.

Comment: svnsync is part of the client tools. you will create a local repository, but you do not need a server as you can access the local repository via file:// URL